# How to build wordpress menu horizontal correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help with menu issue I don't know how to continue from here.
this is my first theme which I build.

[I have template which look like:](http://www.centerwow.com/main/portfolio/112/)

[And I am tring to convert it to theme wordpress](http://www.centerwow.com/roei/22072012/orenramhab/)

I can not build the menu correctly would love to get help thanks.

1. In the page I set 5 name page ( About, Contact, Home, Service, Tours ).
2. In the menu I set name to manu as "top_header" and I select all the page ( About, Contact, Home, Service, Tours ) 
   then I press button add to menu.

in the template the code lookink as below:

```
****************
 <nav>
    <div id="menu-icon">Menu <span></span></div>
    <ul class="sf-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index-1.html">tours</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Myrtle Beach</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Aruba</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Caribbean</a>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Cabo San Lucas</a>
           </li>
           <li class="last-item"><a href="#">Multi-Locations</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Florida</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hawaii</a>
    </li>
    <li class="last-item"><a href="#">Cancun</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index-2.html">hotels</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index-3.html">services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="last-item"><a href="index-4.html">contacts</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
****************
```

.

```
in my theme the code look as below:
****************
    header.php
        <nav id="menu-icon" ><span></span></div>
     <ul class="sf-menu">
           <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top_header' ) ); ?></a>
           </li>
         </ul>                      
 </nav>



function.php
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

    function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu', 'top_header' ) );
    }
****************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@yossi

There is nested list issue in your HTML code and applying CSS.

Also, many of your JS are not binding in theme due to unwanted DOT (.) after yossi_theme in JS source Path, can you look into this below...

http://www.centerwow.com/roei/22072012/orenramhab/wp-content/themes/yossi_theme./js/superfish.js

Also you will find almost 4 to 5 occurrence of same issue followed in other JS SRC path.

Whereas same /yossi_theme/ SRC path was correct in http://www.centerwow.com/roei/22072012/orenramhab/wp-content/themes/yossi_theme/style.css

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: you right in my local host there is no problem with js Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

convert to nav code to:

```
<nav>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```